# Перезагрузка из Windows в Linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub, поиск-программ, dual-boot

Установлены две системы - Windows 7 и Linux Mint 17. Загрузчик - grub, по умолчанию загружает Windows (и это так и надо).

Иногда надо перезагрузиться из Windows в Linux. Windows выключается долго, поэтому находиться за компьютером и караулить, когда же в меню загрузки нужно будет выбрать линукс, не хочется.

Возможно ли как-то в виндоусе организовать автоматическую перезагрузку в линукс, чтобы не надо было руками ничего выбирать в меню?

Драйвер файловой системы установлен и файлы линуксового раздела доступны, однако, по умолчанию, это readonly-доступ. Изменить можно, но что-то мне подсказывает, что неспроста он readonly. Есть ли варианты кроме разрешения доступа на запись и изменения конфигурации grub'а перед перезагрузкой с последующим восстановлением конфигурации из Linux'а? Насколько плоха такая идея? Или как лучше всего её реализовать?

Comment: Не по теме: а если вместо перезагрузки отправлять винду в спящий режим, может станет приемлемо по скорости (если ничего не заглючит)?

Comment: @andreymal, во-первых, говорят, что при гибернации [не сбрасывается файловый кэш на диск](http://ithappens.me/story/12950), что может плохо кончиться. Во-вторых, с гибернацией в принципе проблемы - [снова не работает](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=44326) (с момента установки системы, на этот раз). Если можешь помочь с гибернацией, скажи - задам тут отдельный вопрос.

Comment: А по теме: вин8/вин10 как-то умеет перезагружаться прямо в настройки uefi; если комп с uefi и не лень его настроить, то, может, есть смысл поискать инфу, как такая перезагрузка делается, может, так же можно и в другую ОС загрузиться (а конкретно помочь ничем не могу, сам виндой не пользуюсь)

Comment: @andreymal, нет, uefi нет. Насколько я знаю, теоретически для моей материнки он возможен, но что-то мне не хочется её трогать. Менее радикальные варианты есть?

Comment: @andreymal Кстати, а ведь при установке системы как-то делается перезагрузка не с диска, несмотря на то, что диск вставлен. Не из той же оперы?

Comment: А такого мне встречать не доводилось, бывало что ошибочно повторно с диска грузился (хотя может просто слишком давно винду не ставил и отстал от прогресса)

Comment: @andreymal, если я правильно помню, инсталлятор копирует файлы на диск, потом делает перезагрузку при вставленном диске, но запроса на нажатие клавиши для загрузки с dvd не происходит, сразу делается загрузка с жёсткого диска. Хотя могу ошибаться, редко систему ставлю.

Comment: ИМХО, теоретически это возможно. Делаем маленький раздел с FAT, доступный на запись обоим ОС. В него кладём файл-флажок. Если файл есть, грузимся в Linux, если нет - в Windows. Причём, вроде, `/boot` можно и на FAT ставить, так что, вероятно, можно будет обойтись без отдельного раздела.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не я не хочу отключать таймаут, что каждый раз выбирать систему.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я не хочу ничего нажимать. Всё должно грузиться само без моего вмешательства. И мне не надо оставлять диалог, чтобы вернуться и нажать - в таком случае я могу вместо перезагрузки выбрать выключение. Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы перезагрузка была сразу в linux, без выбора в меню.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я в принципе не против изменения конфигурации, но я опасяюсь разрешать доступ на запись к линуксовому разделу. Кстати, а нельзя ли хранить конфиг груба на разделе с виндой?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, винда на ntfs. Раздела с файлами загрузчика нет - он лежит на обычном линуксовом. По поводу доступа, но ведь не случайно по умолчанию сделан readonly и на изменение запрашивается подтверждение, а точно ли я хочу это сделать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 1. Я имел в виду, что он на том же разделе, где стоит минт. 2. К драйверам линуксовых файловых систем прилагается программа, которая позволяет назначать букву диска этим разделам и настраивать права доступа. Переключение из readonly в read-write делается без проблем. Но разделы, которые винда понимает сама, ей вроде без надобности. 3. Обычно рекомендуют перед созданием новых разделов (а это будет сопровождаться изменением существующих) делать резервную копию диска. На неё у меня места нет, как-то без создания нового раздела можно?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я имел в виду, можно ли расположить конфиг груба на существующем ntfs-разделе? И как это сделать? Кстати, нашёл интересную [статью](//geektimes.ru/post/99159/) - я так понимаю, там речь о grub legacy? Нельзя ли пойти этим путём и из виндового загрузкика запустить нечто?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin _"и сам бы никогда за такое не взялся"_ - почему?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35719/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: Проще всего будет написать два скрипта в windows и linux которые в grub.cfg будут менять очередность загрузки

Comment: @IntFloat, для этого конфиг груба должен быть доступен на запись из винды. Насколько безопасно открывать доступ на запись к линуксовому разделу и почему по умолчанию выставлено readonly?

Comment: Не вижу проблем с безопасностью. А раздел с какой файловой системой? Под бут можно отдельный раздел выделить с fat16/fat32. А раздел с linux в ext4, винда эту файловую систему по умолчанию не поддерживает.

Comment: @IntFloat, возможно, дело в том, что инсталляторы начнут его замусоривать временными файлами? msi же выбирает диск, на котором больше всего свободного места, независимо от того, чем он является.

Comment: На бут разделе много свободного места не нужно, мегабайт 100-200 хватит, и msi туда мусорить не будет

Comment: @IntFloat, ну т. е. всё сводится к тому, что нужен отдельный раздел под настройки груба, а разрешать доступ к разделу с самим линуксом не стоит - верно?

Comment: Обычно раздел линукса имеет файловую систему которую windows не поддерживает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36415/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-intfloat).

Answer (score 10):

например, можно перенести содержимое каталога `/boot` в раздел с файловой системой, с которой отлично работают и *ms/windows* и *gnu/linux* — *msdos/fat* (оно же *fat32*, оно же *vfat* и т.п.).

тогда можно будет устанавливать в файле `/boot/grub/grubenv` переменной окружения `next_entry` нужный пункт из загрузочного меню (нумерация начинается с нуля).

важный момент: этот файл [должен быть размером ровно 1024 байта](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Environment-block.html). как именно должно выглядеть содержимое файла с новой командой, можно выяснить «на кошках», передав первым параметром путь к какому-нибудь тестовому файлу. вот эта команда установит значение переменной `next_entry`:

```
$ grub-editenv /tmp/file set next_entry=1
```

а вот эта — удалит упоминание данной переменной:

```
$ grub-editenv /tmp/file unset next_entry
```

p.s. после переноса содержимого надо, естественно, добавить строчку в `/etc/fstab` для монтирования раздела, куда вынесено содержимое каталога `/boot`. примерно так:

```
/dev/раздел /boot auto defaults 0 0
```

или так:

```
UUID="uuid-раздела" /boot auto defaults 0 0
```

`uuid-раздела` можно узнать из вывода команды:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="7ff90d2c-656f-4d31-bde3-6aa0f57c57e1" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="BB52-4408" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e5311d67-01"
```

---

**обновление**. протестировал. вполне уверенно срабатывает «одноразовая» функциональность: после загрузки значение переменной `next_entry` в файле `/boot/grub/grubenv` было благополучно «затёрто».

Comment: _"после загрузки значение переменной next_entry в файле /boot/grub/grubenv было благополучно «затёрто»"_ - это затирание надо в каждой системе реализовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, его не надо реализовывать. оно уже реализовано. в программе *grub*.

Comment: можно подготовить пару таких файлов  и подсовывать их простым копированием для запуска из виндовс