# Добавление новых пунктов выключения в Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, dual-boot

Сейчас у меня на одном ПК две ОС: Ubuntu 17.04 и Windows 10. Иногда, когда надо перейти с Ubuntu на Windows не хочется ждать перезапуск ПК что бы выбрать Windows в Grub(на автозапуске стоит Ubuntu, что бы при переходе не неё не ждать перезагрузки). Можно ли добавить к стандартным пунктам 'Перезагрузить' и 'Выключить' пункт при выборе, которого будет перезагружен ПК и автоматом стартанёт Windows?

Comment: ответ на буквальный вопрос: нет. а если не буквально, а по сути, то это дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/492090/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не вижу принципиальной невозможности добавить такой пункт в меню... конечно, в крайнем случае, это потребует пропатчить третьегном с его меню и написать небольшой демон, который будет мордой к `grub-editenv` (если этого ещё нет в systemd), но это не то чтобы невыполнимо... к тому же есть готовые примеры...