# Быстрая перезагрузка между windows 10 и ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, загрузка, dual-boot, загрузчик

На компьютере стоят windows 10 и ubuntu 16. Можно ли из запущенной windows 10 сразу отправлять команду на перезагрузку в ubuntu 16 и наоборот. То есть как можно отправить команду на перезагрузку в другой раздел жесткого диска?(меню загрузчика в начале запуска компьютера не считается) На Mac OS в boot camp такая вещь была реализована, такого функционал нельзя сделать на всех ОС?

Comment: Нет. Если линукс используется для написания прог без интерфейса, ставьте на win10 wsl вместо линукс и не парьтесь. Будут работать одновременно.

Comment: Для перезагрузки с ubuntu напрямую в другую операционку вроде бы нашел.
Называется Unity Reboot. 
Установка:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-reboot

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/492090/178988 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785013/178988

Answer (score 1):

Для перезагрузки с ubuntu напрямую в другую операционку вроде бы нашел.
Называется Unity Reboot.

http://compizomania.blogspot.com/2013/01/unity-reboot-ubuntu-13041210.html